# Drop down list creation based on input entered in the search bar angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to use angular for one for one my projects.

Say i have a search bar and i give some input in that search bar, now if that input is present in say an array in the controller then below that search bar those options should be displayed.

For example in my input textbox i give keyword 'hey' and in my array i have keywords like 'heya','heylo' and 'heyme'. Then all 3 keywords should come below input search box.

I was trying to search this but am not still able to find something convincing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your array is in the controller and is attached to your $scope

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Answer (score 0):

I was trying hands on by inspecting elements in few webpages using angular, so i got how it works. Just below search bar a div can be created and in that div ng-repeat can be used to populate values as list indexes. Now this div is only shown when the inputText matches the one in the controller array, this can be done by using ng-show.